# static_assert if expressions is constexpr

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, static-assert

I want to create a class template

```
template <class T>
class X {
  // here I'll use T::value (among other things)
};
```

`T::value` will often be a constexpr static variable, but not always. `T::value` has to be positive value, so I want to let people know it during compilation, when possible.

If `T::value` was always constexpr, I'd add `static_assert` like

```
static_assert(T::value > 0, "need positive number");
```

Is it possible to add this static_assert only for cases when `T::value` is constexpr?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can write an `is_valid` template function (come up with a better name) with two overloads:

```
template <typename T, int N = T::value>
constexpr bool is_valid(int) {
    return N > 0;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_valid(...) {
    return true;
}
```

The first overload will only be valid if `T::value` is a constant expression, otherwise it will be SFINAEd out. The second overload is valid no matter what, so we disambiguate the overload with a dummy `int` parameter.

Now we test it like so:

```
static_assert(is_valid<T>(0), "need positive number");
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8282052384aad7c8)

Comment: Cool. Would be even more cool if implementation didn't have to know that it depends on T::value (i.e so that one could write `static_assert(some_func(T::value > 0), "")` as well as `static_assert(some_func(T::other_value > T::third_value()), "")`

Comment: @RiaD Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/074b7425dc9f3c18)? At that point you're essentially implementing Concepts ;).

Comment: Well, it's not much better because still requires to create a trait for each condition, but yep, I meant something similar

Comment: Ideal would be function like `return_value_if_constexpr_otherwise_true`. It would be easy to write it if there was constexpr-based overloading :)

Comment: Sadly, `template <class F> constexpr auto is_constexpr(F f) -> std::enable_if_t<((void)f(),true), std::true_type>` does not seem to work (even with constexpr lambda), as you cannot use parameters before the function body starts.

Comment: But `is_valid<>()` takes a type. What if you just have a `struct Bar{ int value; };` (not static), but use it as `constexpr Bar b = {5};`? That is `constexpr`, but you cannot call an `is_valid` on it.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me on clang++:

```
#include <type_traits>

// The default case, returns true if the value is not constant.
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsNonConstantOrPositive {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// The `constexpr` case. We check if we can evaluate `T::value == 0` which can only
// be evaluated at compile-time if `T::value` is constant. The whole `enable_if` thing
// is to provide a substitution to ensure SFINAE.
template <typename T>
struct IsNonConstantOrPositive<T, typename std::enable_if<T::value==0||true>::type> {
    static const bool value = T::value > 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct X {
    static_assert(IsNonConstantOrPositive<T>::value, "T::value should be positive");
};
```

Example:

```
struct A {  // const > 0, should succeed
    static const int value = 123;
};

struct B {  // const <= 0, should fail
    static const int value = -1234;
};

struct C {   // non-const, should succeed
    static int value;
};

int main() {
    X<A> a;     // ok
    //X<B> b;   // error
    X<C> c;     // ok
}
```

Comment: Can you _explain_ your solution? Surprised to see a 300k user giving a raw code dump. You should know that that's not what we do here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be nice to have a test for const(expr)-ness of a variable, to be used like:

```
struct T {
    ...
    static_assert(!IS_CONSTANT_VAR(value) || value > 0, "trouble is afoot");
};
```

The implementation below uses a similar strategy to kennytm's solution to fail out on non-constant references. It works in Clang and GCC.

```
#include <type_traits> // enable_if

template<typename T, T& var, typename = void> struct is_constant_var_impl {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
template<typename T, T& var>
struct is_constant_var_impl <T, var, typename std::enable_if<(double)var == (double)var>::type> {
    // (double) cast above to thwart GCC's agressive constant folding;
    // perhaps could be removed with a bit more finesse
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
#define IS_CONSTANT_VAR(...) (is_constant_var_impl<decltype(__VA_ARGS__), (__VA_ARGS__)>::value)
```

#### Pros

- Template can be reused across different classes or static member names
- Self-explanatory code in the `static_assert`

#### Cons

- Does not work in MSVC
- (Maybe?) Uses C++14
- Gross

Comment: few comments 1) could you explain why `static_assert(!IS_CONSTANT_VAR(value) || value > 0`, "") works, considering it depends on value. Is it guaranteed? (I checked and it does on my compiler)  (it's basically works same as static_assert(true || value > 0,  "") which I believe shouldn't work. 2) what is from c++14, It compiled fine with std=c++11 for me (on clang) 3) I'd better use named arg for macro than VA_ARGS consifering only single argument supported

Comment: @RiaD (1) The short-circuiting effect of `||` also works at compile time so it does not depend on `value` if the first argument is true. But I can't guarantee anything :) (2) Hmm, I thought I saw something about constexpr or reference parameters which required C++14, but now I can't find what it was. But it fails in g++ -std=c++11. (3) Since C++ can have expressions with unbracketed commas (from template arguments) I like to do this so it will still work with those but it's a matter of taste.